# Solution of exponential integral using Dirac delta Fourier integral expression

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I'm trying to solve this integral that appears in L.I. Deych's "Advanced Undergraduate Quantum Mechanics", which is supposed to be a self-teaching book but has no solution manual. The book offers a hint: "Use the representation of the delta-function as a Fourier integral to figure out the integral with respect to *k*."

$$\int ^{+\infty }_{-\infty }dxf\left( x\right) \int ^{+\infty }_{-\infty }dkke^{ik\left( x-x'\right) }$$

I've used integration by parts for the integral with respect to *k*, but to no avail. Any further hints?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, joriki. I've changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

The book want you to use the fact that
$$\int \mathrm{d} t \, e^{- i \omega t} e^{i a t} = 2 \pi \delta(\omega - a)$$
And we have that
$$\int \mathrm{d}t \, t^n f(t) e^{-i \omega t}=i^{n}\frac{\mathrm{d}^nF(\omega)}{\mathrm{d}\omega^n}$$
So we have that
$$\int \mathrm{d}k \, k e^{i k (x-x')}=i\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x'}\bigg(2 \pi \delta(x'-x)\bigg)=2i \pi \frac{\mathrm{d}\delta(x'-x)}{\mathrm{d}x'}$$

Comment: Thank you, Botond. Yes, that was the hint offered by the book. Any other hint? Is integration by parts the way to go?

Comment: @Dirac I added an extra step. I think it's better now.